# Relationships of missing values for exploratory analysis

Tags: missing-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a survey with 30 questions on a seven item likert scale
Not all of the questions were answered. I can use a heat map to visualize the missing answers but what i would like to know is if there is a pattern related to the missing values verses the answers in the questions. So for example if 20 people have skipped answering question 6 (How much do you earn) and all those people have answered item 6 on question 20 (I earn less than 20,000), this would be an interesting pattern. Does any know of a technique that might be useful for this?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create missing value indicator fields for each question that contains missing answers. For instance, if QUESTION_1 contains some missing answers, then create QUESTION_1_MISS field that will be equal to 1 when the answer is missing, otherwise 0.

Once you create such missing value indicator flags, you can perform a correlation analysis to study pairwise correlations between (a) each missing value indicator field, and (b) the original fields in your table that contain the actual answers.

This analysis should reveal any relationship such as the one you described in your example.

Keep in mind that the sample size is small, so you may not find strong correlations. If you run into this issue, you may want to consider bootstrapping (random sampling with replacement) to artificially increase your sample size for this analysis.